# Request for PDO experience, the best there is?

Tags: php, pdo

I'm about to migrate from mysqli to PDO and would like some feedback on how it's related to other similar solutions regardning speed, security and db-portability. Any experience welcome.

regards,
/t

Comment: This is not a discussion forum. You can't ask that here.

Comment: @dan, I requesting experience, not arguments. I do see your point though..

Comment: SO is for specific questions with specific answers. There is no right answer to "share your experience".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speed, portability, and security are really the only reasons TO move to PDO from the mysql_ specific functions in PHP.  You're moving from a database-specific method to abstracting your database access - when it comes to db portability, this is IT.

If you're using mysql_query all over the place in your code, you'll have some getting used to when it comes time start using object methods instead.  Code practice aside, you'll soon come to wonder how you ever did it any other way! :)